# PHP preg_match_all to extract number with or without decimal

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to extract any number out from a string (with or without decimal) and dump that into an array. Below is my code

```
$matches = array();
$str = "I have string of 21.11 out of 30";
preg_match_all("/\d+/",$str,$matches);
echo var_dump($matches);
```

The current output has 3 elements below:

21

11

30

But I expect to output only 2 elements below:

21.11

30

How do I change my regex?

Comment: Try `[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this regex (add dot in character class) :

```
$matches = array();
$str = "I have string of 21.11 out of 30";
preg_match_all("/[\d\.]+/",$str,$matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

[Test it](http://www.tehplayground.com/#lNvc1YA7p) (Ctrl + Enter)

Comment: just no need to echo the `var_dump` but nice solution.

Comment: You're right, it's superfluous.

Comment: Thanks, Jedema, it works!

Comment: Hi Jedema, how about if I want to extact number with only numeric only and ignore word with number? For example, those words with number, such as "d7" or "abc100" I do not want to extract the number since it is part of word.

Comment: It's not very elegant but it works : http://www.tehplayground.com/#5YuA8Oaq9